# nsPopover triangle not appearing on the popover

Tags: nspopover

I have used the Less version of the scss they have . I used grunt scss2less tool to generate it. Now after adding the less file and integrating I dont see the triangle part of the popover. Any help would be appreciated. I have raised the pull request for the less file in the nsPopover repo.